# My marquee control is not working in IE 6

Tags: html

A marguee with direction="up" is not working in IE 6. How can I fix this, or is there another solution?

Comment: The `<marquee>` tag is deprecated and should be avoided

Comment: i feel like voting to close as "not a real question". Are you serious?

Comment: Thank goodness it isn't working

Comment: +1 @Andrew Bullock - I reported it. This is just trolling.

Comment: Trying to close this question (again).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marquee should never be used as it is dead. For a cross browser scrolling effect please use a javascript tool like this:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Oh my... IE6? Why on Earth you care about details under this browser?

1. `<marquee>` is not a part of HTML specification - use JavaScript instead.
2. It's 2010 - dump IE6 or at least don't care about details.